# Discussion Forum can't find a few includes

Tags: forum, discussion

I have undertaken the arduous task of skinning the discussion forum.

I have almost completed it, but can't figure out where a few things are stored.

1. In the localization settings page, where are the forms stored? `{form:localization}, {form:time_format}, {form:language}`
2. In the preview message, and view message pages, I can't find the parsed message include. `{include:parsed_message}`
3. On the view thread pages, the code `{if avatar}{/if}` works, but `{if no_avatar}{/if}` doesn't. I want to include an alternative default image if the user has no avatar stored. Is there a way to do this?

If anyone can point me in the right direction on any of the points about, that would be fantastic.

Have a great Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find it here:
 - "ROOT_FOLDER"\themes\forum_themes\default\forum_global

Comment: Could you try to expand on this answer to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

For item 3 on your list try:

```
{if avatar}
    ...stuff...
{if:else}
    ...other stuff...
{/if}
```